# Как добавлять информацию в xml-файл

Tags: c#, xml

Есть вот такая база данных. Добавляю несколько полей в DGV, а потом мне нужно в обработчике событие(Import in XML) все те данные что были в DGV импортировать в XML файл.Код сериализации вставлял в кнопку Add, но тогда в XML сохранить мог только одну запись,ту которую добавлял первую. А мне надо сначал добавить несколько в грид, а тогда все в XML.

[image: БД]

```
////кнопка add
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 friendForm = new Form2();
    DialogResult result = friendForm.ShowDialog(this);

    if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
        return;
    friends friends = new friends();
    friends.FirstName = friendForm.textBox1.Text;
    friends.LastName = friendForm.textBox2.Text;
    friends.Age = (int)friendForm.numericUpDown1.Value;
    friends.Number = friendForm.textBox3.Text;
    friends.House = (int)friendForm.numericUpDown2.Value;
    friends.Adress = friendForm.textBox4.Text;

    db.friendsSet.Add(friends);
    db.SaveChanges();

    XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(friends));
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory +
        "\\book.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        serial.Serialize(fs, friends);
        MessageBox.Show("XML was created");
    }
}
```

Comment: М-м-м... Вообще-то, должно быть "Export **to** XML", "Import **from** XML". Экспорт куда-то, Импорт откуда-то.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, следует подумать: а нужно ли дублировать данные в xml-файл, если они уже сохранены в БД? База данных для того и предназначена, чтобы данные можно было легко добавлять, удалять, изменять, искать. Если для каких-то целей всё же понадобятся данные в формате xml, то их всегда можно получить прямо из БД. Одна из возможностей - команда [`FOR XML`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms178107.aspx).

---

Ответ непосредстенно на ваш вопрос. Заведите список объектов `Friend` (переименуйте класс, Visual Studio автоматически сделает изменения во всём проекте).

```
List<Friend> _friends = new List<Friend>();
```

Это должно быть поле той формы, где выполняется сериализация.

Получив очередной экземпляр этого класса, добавляйте его в эту коллекцию:

```
Friend friend = new Friend();
friend.FirstName = friendForm.textBox1.Text;
...

db.friendsSet.Add(friend);
db.SaveChanges();

_friends.Add(friend); // добавляем в список
```

Когда ввод всех данных будет закончен, сериализуем весь список:

```
XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Friend>)); // <--

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory +
    "\\book.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    serial.Serialize(fs, _friends); // <--
    MessageBox.Show("XML was created");
}
```

Судя по скриншоту, этот код следует поместить в обработчик кнопки "Export". Кстати, вызов `db.SaveChanges();` я бы перенёс туда же.

Обратите внимание: сериализатор должен быть создан соответствующего типа; на вход ему подаём не один экземпляр, а коллекцию.

Десериализовать, соответственно, нужно коллекцию, выполняя приведение к `List<Friend>`.

Comment: большое спасибо) но тепер ошибка "Тип сущности Friends не входит в модель для текущего контекста" в процесе компиляции

Comment: @OleksandrPavlyshyn - Если не знаете, как исправить контекст, то не переименовывайте класс.

Comment: ой дурак, все зделал и контекст и все работает как нужно,большое спасибо, что я бы делал без вас)